# Accumulating sum in one line in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

Is it possible to do this in one line with the goal of getting the accumulated sum equal to n?

```
int n = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    n += i;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a LINQ extension method for that:

```
static int SlowSum1ToN(int N)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, N).Sum();
}
```

However, you can also calculate this particular value (the sum of an arithmetic sequence) [without iterating at all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum):

```
static int FastSum1ToN(int N)
{
    return (N * (1 + N)) / 2;
}
```

Comment: ...but now -1 for your broken implementation of it.

Comment: Haha, whoops. Somehow I had a feeling I'd make a mistake like that. I think instead of unit tests for TDD I should just post code on SO; you can get faster feedback that way ;)

Comment: return (N * (1 + N)) >> 1; is about another 35% faster on my core2duo. +1 for math.

Comment: @Bengie: try keeping the `/2`, but using `uint` instead of `int`. Does that fix the performance too?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, seems uint puts them about the same speed. My guess is the shift wouldn't work on a negative signed int, but in this case we have no negative numbers. The compiler can't figure that out. At least that's my guess. Good point though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible, you can do that using [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) to generate a sequence of integer numbers and then call the LINQ extension method [Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#sumSimple) as the following:

```
int result = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Sum();
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes

You can replace

```
int S = 0

for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
{
    S += i;
}
```

with

`int S = (N*(N+1))/2`

Comment: Your mathematical formula `N*(N+1)/2` is absolutely correctly, but it will result in more than one lines of code.

Comment: @Waqas: What do you mean? Isn't it one line? Are you talking about assembly?

Answer (score 1):

As an added answer, there is also the `Aggregate` function which is more general than `Sum`:

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a += b);
```

So you can also do stuff like

```
// multiply 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 ...
var product = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Aggregate(1, (a, b) => a *= b);
```

Comment: I think you mean `(a, b) => a + b`. `a += b` is not wrong, as it evaluates to `a + b`, but there's no point in assigning the result to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

What's the fascination with one liners?  Here it is:

`int n = 0; for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {n += i;}`

Is there a better way to calculate this?  Sure.  See the other answers that use a formula.

Comment: you're not cool unless your entire app is just one line of code.

Comment: @Matt: indeed, that's *the* major advance in Java and C# compared with C and C++ - by removing the preprocessor there is no longer any need for linebreaks.